# AJAX Inconsistant Return Value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax call to a PHP script on a server with a USB temperature probe inserted. When the temperature is over 100, the ajax call doesn't consistently return the proper temperature. Sometimes it returns the complete temperature (i.e. 145.78), sometimes it just returns the over 100 part (i.e. 45.78).

Running the PHP script from the command line produces a consistent result every time; regardless of how many times in a row I run it.

I created another PHP file and just had it echo out 123.45 and ran that through the ajax call, and it seemed to return the complete number consistently.

Here is the sample code pertaining to this:

**JS**

```
function monitorLoop() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'temp0.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });

}

$("#toggleMonitor").on( "click", function() {
    looping = !looping;
    if (looping) {
        loop = setInterval( function() { monitorLoop(); }, 1000 );
    } else {
        clearInterval( loop );
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $pattern = '/[0-9]*[0-9][0-9]\.[0-9][0-9]/';

    $temperature = exec('sudo pcsensor -f -n0');
    preg_match( $pattern, $temperature, $output, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    echo $output[0][0];
?>
```

And here is the output from both the console and the commandline:

**Console**

```
"90.74" brewery.js:47
"90.29" brewery.js:47
"90.29" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.39" brewery.js:47
"89.61" brewery.js:47
```

**Command Line**

```
190.29pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.40pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.85pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
191.08pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.96pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.29pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.62pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
190.18pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
189.61pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
189.39pi@raspberrypi /var/www $ php temp0.php
```

It seemed to get a bit better when I slowed the interval from 1000 ms to 2000 or even 3000 ms, but it still wasn't consistent. The run that I posted above was with the interval set to 2000, and it never showed the whole number.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't deal well with more than one request in parallel?

Comment: I realized as I was telling someone else about this problem that if I switched my whole system over to Celsius it wouldn't be an issue. I could even convert to Fahrenheit after pulling the Celsius reading if I needed to.

Comment: I considered the parallel requests, but if I make a command line request at the same time it is looping through the web page it just errors.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you run your script `temp0.php` via a browser ?